# ISBLANK(INDEX.... not recognizing blank cells

Tags: excel, vba, indexing

I have this formula that checks to see if a cell is blank and then if it is blank returns the cell before it. The formula works, but only works once I have clicked into the blank cell.

How can I have this fixed? Macros? Settings? Anything?

Here is the function

```
IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(INDEX('Member Admissions'!$A$12:$T$3386,'Member Admissions'!$W17,16)),INDEX('Member Admissions'!$A$12:$T$3386,'Member Admissions'!$W17,15),INDEX('Member Admissions'!$A$12:$T$3386,'Member Admissions'!$W17,16)),"")
```

Again, the function works... but only after I go in to the blank cell it is referencing and I click into the cell and hit enter.

edit: I can also select the cells with the cursor and press the "delete" key and the function will work properly then, too.

Thanks

Comment: Is your calculation mode set to 'Manual'?

Comment: AJD, 
My Calculation Options are set to Automatic.